# Windows Form (C#) -- Clicking buttons without leaving mouse click

Tags: c#, windows, forms, button

I'm trying to build an application using C#, which will visualize some graph searching algorithms.
For that, I opened a Windows Form and inserted 50X50 buttons to it.
[image]

I know how to make the buttons do something specific everytime I click it.

But the problem that I encounter is, I want to press the mouse-clickbutton ONCE, and without leaving the mouse-clickbutton, I want EVERY BUTTON I PASS ON to be pressed.

For example, I want to press the whole first line of buttons.
I can press each button separately, but instead, I want to click one of the buttons, and without leaving my mouse button pressed, I want to pass by all the buttons and make them clicked.

I want that my mouse click would mark as many buttons as its pressed, and if my mouse button is not pressed, nothing would happen.
I hope my question is understandable. Can anyone please point me where I can find this solution? I googled my vision but couldn't find anyone getting to understand my idea.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about using the MouseDown event to set `bool MouseIsDown`, and MouseUp event to unset it.  Then use MouseEnter on each button, and check if `MouseIsDown`? [MouseEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-mouse/events?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: You are likely to find that doing this without using a 50x50 matrix of buttons will be faster than using 2500 buttons.  Windows isn't really designed to work well with a window containing 2500 contained windows (a button is a full-on Win32 window).  If you don't have the entire surface covered in buttons, you will have a single window.  That way, you can have one place that (the form) that manages all the user interactions.  Just draw rectangles

Comment: @Flydog57 I haven't yet learnt using xaml  / xml files, and it's quite impossible to use Rectangles with a simple .cs file. For example, I don't have any fill or other mandatory commands to use on a rectangle. Do you think using a PictureBox instead of a button is a better solution? Or I would face the same problem as now?